# In Entity Framework 4.1 how can I use SqlQuery to create anonymous objects where the query details are not known at compile time

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4.1, anonymous-types

I'm using EF 4.1 and need to use **DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>** to run a stored proc which will effectively do **SELECT * FROM table** where **table** may not even exist at compile time.

I'm probably being thick but I haven't a clue what to use for **<T>** which will represent an object containing the data from a single row in the table.

I'm not going to be operating on the resulting objects of type **<T>** but they will eventually be serialised into JSON.

If I'm asking the impossible or unfeasable, pointers to an easier route would be very welcome!

Pete Sykes

Answer (score 0):

The generic in this event is an object to which to map the results. Even if you're just serializing them, you need to put the results into a list of something.

Comment: Thanks Hammerstein. I probably wasn't clear - I understand generics and that **<T>** is the type to receive each row of the results but the issue is that I don't know at compile time any details of the table that might be queried - indeed, the table might not even exist at compile time so it's not possible to code a class for it.  I thought anonymous objects might help but I haven't found a way to use them here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently researching a similar problem.  So far, I've found [this blog entry](http://www.markzhou.com/blog/post/2011/06/02/Use-dynamic-type-in-Entity-Framework-41-SqlQuery()-method.aspx).  It will probably solve your problem, however, I'm a bit wary of creating types on the fly.